# Объединение двух объектов в одну программу

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, функции, объекты

Первоначально было две задачи: создать класс Аккаунт, со своими данными, в т.ч. суммой денег в рублях; создать класс Деньги, где будут представлены рубли и копейки. Третья задача заключается в том, чтобы использовать класс Деньги, в классе Аккаунт. Я почти все методы переделал, кроме последнего: написать сумму денег прописью. Как мне правильно преобразовать этот метод?
Код прилагаю:

```
char* toString(int num, char *s)
{
int position = 0;
int x[4];
int div = 1000;
int var = num;


int rest;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    rest = (int)(var / div);
    x[i] = rest;
    var = var - rest*div;
    div = div / 10;
  }

  switch (x[0])
  {
    case 1: strcpy(s, "Одна тысяча "); break;
    case 2: strcpy(s, "Две тысячи "); break;
    case 3: strcpy(s, "Три тысячи "); break;
    case 4: strcpy(s, "Четыре тысячи "); break;
    case 5: strcpy(s, "Пять тысяч "); break;
    case 6: strcpy(s, "Шесть тысяч "); break;
    case 7: strcpy(s, "Семь тысяч "); break;
    case 8: strcpy(s, "Восемь тысяч "); break;
    case 9: strcpy(s, "Девять тысяч "); break;
    default: break;
  }
  position = strlen(s);

  switch (x[1])
  {
    case 1: strcpy(s + position, "сто "); break;
    case 2: strcpy(s + position, "двести "); break;
    case 3: strcpy(s + position, "триста "); break;
    case 4: strcpy(s + position, "четыреста "); break;
    case 5: strcpy(s + position, "пятьсот "); break;
    case 6: strcpy(s + position, "шестьсот "); break;
    case 7: strcpy(s + position, "семьсот "); break;
    case 8: strcpy(s + position, "восемьсот "); break;
    case 9: strcpy(s + position, "девятьсот "); break;
    default: break;
  }
  position = strlen(s);

  switch (x[2])
  {
    case 1:

    switch (x[3])
    {
      case 0: strcpy(s + position, "десять "); break;
      case 1: strcpy(s + position, "одиннадцать "); break;
      case 2: strcpy(s + position, "двенадцать "); break;
      case 3: strcpy(s + position, "тринадцать "); break;
      case 4: strcpy(s + position, "четырнадцать "); break;
      case 5: strcpy(s + position, "пятнадцать "); break;
      case 6: strcpy(s + position, "шестнадцать "); break;
      case 7: strcpy(s + position, "семнадцать "); break;
      case 8: strcpy(s + position, "восемнадцать "); break;
      case 9: strcpy(s + position, "девятнадцать "); break;
    }
    x[3] = 0;
    position = strlen(s);
    break;
    case 2: strcpy(s + position, "двадцать "); break;
    case 3: strcpy(s + position, "тридцать "); break;
    case 4: strcpy(s + position, "сорок "); break;
    case 5: strcpy(s + position, "пятьдесят "); break;
    case 6: strcpy(s + position, "шестьдесят "); break;
    case 7: strcpy(s + position, "семьдесят "); break;
    case 8: strcpy(s + position, "восемьдесят "); break;
    case 9: strcpy(s + position, "девяносто "); break;
    default: break;
  }
  position = strlen(s);

  switch (x[3]) {
    case 1: strcpy(s + position, "один "); break;
    case 2: strcpy(s + position, "два "); break;
    case 3: strcpy(s + position, "три "); break;
    case 4: strcpy(s + position, "четыре "); break;
    case 5: strcpy(s + position, "пять "); break;
    case 6: strcpy(s + position, "шесть "); break;
    case 7: strcpy(s + position, "семь "); break;
    case 8: strcpy(s + position, "восемь "); break;
    case 9: strcpy(s + position, "девять "); break;
    default: break;
  }
  position = strlen(s);
  return s;
}

std::string Account::toString (Money&st) const
{
char* str;
char s[100];
int choice1 = st.get_kopeck();
//int choice2 = st.get_ruble();
*str = toString(choice, s);*
//str = toString(choice2, s);
return str;
   }
```

В курсивной строчке выдаёт ошибку: error: no matching function for call to 'Account::toString(int&, char [100]) const'.
   Если нужно вся программа я могу приложить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажите ему, что вам нужна *внешняя* функция, из глобального пространства имен:

```
str = ::toString(choice, s);
```

А вообще - если уж у вас C++ - то работали бы вы со строками `string`...